# want to show place on google map when input lat,longitude value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show place on google map, when input latitude , longitude value. I want to write that with C#. If anyone has sample, please share me.. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Check [Google Maps API for .NET](http://gmaps.codeplex.com/)